# jQuery — .not() is not working

Tags: jquery, hover, filtering

Here is my code:

```
$("a").not(".current_page_item").hover(
   function(){
      $(this).stop().animate(
          {color: "#ffffff"}, 'slow'
      );
   },
   function(){
      $(this).stop().animate(
         {color: "#666666"}, 'slow'
      );
   }
);
```

If I specifically ask the CSS for the class to change for example:

```
$(".current_page_item").css("color", "#ff00ff");
```

I can change its colour, so I know it's not a fault on my part.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the HTML? Do links have the  class `current_page_item` ? You need **jQuery UI** for color animation. It should work then: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/arU6e/

Comment: `.not()` _does_ work. You made a mistake somewhere. It's a fault on your part.

Comment: Can you put together a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: does $("a.current_page_item").css("color", "#ff00ff"); work as expected? perhaps the current_page_item class is on a parent element?

Comment: You didn't explain what part of the code "is not working". Your demo http://baked-beans.tv/mv/ has animated-colour links for me.

Comment: @Felix Kling @RGBK didn't know jquery UI had a separate animate function. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: On that page, the `current-menu-item` class isn't on the `a`, it's on the `li`. I assume you're trying to make the colors *not* animate for the "current" link.

Comment: Ack, i hate it, yep... it's on the <li> not the <a>. Serves me right for coding on a sunny sunday instead of having a BBQ. My apologies.

Comment: Here it is... working: http://jsfiddle.net/tLMEF/

Comment: How can you ditch BBQ? Shame on you! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the markup in the [demo page](http://baked-beans.tv/mv/), you have to do:

```
$("a").not(".current_page_item > a").hover(...)
```

or alternatively:

```
var selected = $('.current_page_item > a')[0];
$("a").not(selected).hover(...);
```

*(might be faster)*

or just:

```
$("li").not(".current_page_item").hover(...)
```

*(if it also changes the color of the links, not sure about that (links are special ;)))*

`current_page_item` is a class of parent `li`, not the link itself.

Your code only filters links (`a` elements) that have a class `current_page_item`, but none of them has, so it selects all links.